# Match strings to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, mime-types

I need to match strings to other strings, specifically an extension or mime type to the type of file. For example "png","image/png","image/jpeg" should match to "image" etc.

Currently I am using this method:

```
fileFormats = {
    'image/png':'image',
    'image/jpeg':'image',
    'png':'image',
    'jpeg':'image',
    'jpg':'image'
}

fileFormats["png"]
```

However this can get quite repetitive as the number of extensions/mime types rises.
I also think that there should be/is a better way of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you make a map from format name to mime type and/or file extension, there should be no repetition. You can then invert the list:

```
mimeTypes = {
    'image' : ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', ...],
    'text'  : [ . . .],
    . . .
}
fileFormats = {};
for (type in mimeTypes) {
    mimeList = mimeTypes[type];
    for (i = 0, n = mimeList.length; i < n; ++i) {
        fileFormats[mimeList[i]] = type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really, you'll still need a dictionary / map somewhere at some point.

My first comment is that you shouldn't mix MIME and file extensions in the same map. Instead, you should have 2 maps:

```
extensionToMime = {};
mimeToExtension = {};
```

Second comment is that 1 extension can have more than 1 MIME, so the values of the extensionToMime map should be arrays.

However, if you really want to avoid using a map (which will return your result in O(1) btw, hard to do faster), you can still figure out some rules to build the MIME type depending on its extension. For example:

```
 var simpleMimes = { "png":true, "jpeg":true, "gif":true }; // mimicking a set
 // then, when you need it:
 function getMimeFromExtension(ext) {
   if (ext in simpleMimes) {
     return "image/" + ext;
   }
   return extensionToMime[ext];
 }
```

This is obviously not possible for all extensions and it only works if you are working with a small number of MIME that can be easily build like this.